# I want to scrape all business links from this page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all links(not title) of companies. Please guide me! Thanks!
here is the url of web page: https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/nsw/sydney

here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'sc-bZQynM sc-iwsKbI dpKmnV'}).get('href')
    except:
        links = []
    print(links)
def Main():
    r = requests.get("https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/nsw/sydney")
    get_index_data(r)
Main()
```

Comment: what's the `issue` then ? and what `re` is doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/nsw/sydney")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


for item in soup.findAll("h3", {'class': 'sc-bZQynM sc-iwsKbI dpKmnV'}):
    print(f"https://hipages.com.au{item.previous_element.get('href')}")
```

Output:

```
https://hipages.com.au/connect/glencoelectricalbuildingmaintenanceairconditioningsecurityalarmscctv
https://hipages.com.au/connect/emcoelectricalservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/abcelectricservicespl/service/126298
https://hipages.com.au/connect/ozyblindsnscreens
https://hipages.com.au/connect/samedaytvantennaservice
https://hipages.com.au/connect/langenelectricalnsw
https://hipages.com.au/connect/allprohandymanmaintenance
https://hipages.com.au/connect/amateairconditioningrefrigerationservices
https://hipages.com.au/connect/makeurmove
https://hipages.com.au/connect/uberantennas/service/184323
https://hipages.com.au/connect/cmkelectricalanddata
https://hipages.com.au/connect/antennadistributionservicesptyltd
https://hipages.com.au/connect/sydneysparky
https://hipages.com.au/connect/bluediamond
https://hipages.com.au/connect/digiproantennas
https://hipages.com.au/connect/vascom
https://hipages.com.au/connect/sparkyselectricalanddataptyltd
https://hipages.com.au/connect/prosparksolutions
```

Comment: Thank you bro! You helped me a lot. Stay blessed!

Comment: Bro as you helped me a lot. Please one more time I need your help. Could you please merge this code and previous code for me? Actually I want details of all business from this page url: https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/nsw/sydney You will just have to merge previous program(detail data from single page) and this code means I need details data from all buisness on this url. Pease sir! sorry for asking help again and again

Comment: @MuhammadAkram i suggest you open a separate question for that. Also please try and show research from your end. Stackoverflow is not a platform to hand out your assignments or work directly

Comment: thank you bro Yes definitely some research and effort should be shown from my end and I did and also open a separate question here is the link of that question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556883/how-to-scrape-multiple-result-having-same-tags-and-class   could you please review and help me if you can?