# How to scrape multiple result having same tags and class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is accurate for single page but when I run this code for multiple records using for loop and if there are some data missing like person then (as I used index no[1] and [2] for person variable ,location, phone no and cell no but if there are something missing like person name is missing) next record will be extracted at person variable. Could you please fix this issue?
here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml') # 1. html , 2. parser
    return soup

def get_detail_data(soup):
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        try:
            title = soup.find("h1", {'class': 'sc-AykKI'}).text
        except:
            title = 'Empty Title'
        #print(title)
        try:
            person = soup.find(
            "span", {'class': 'Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee'}).text.strip()
        except:
            person = 'Empty Person'
        #print(person)
        try:
            addr = soup.findAll(
            "span", {'class': 'Contact__Item-sc-1giw2l4-2 kBpGee'})[1].text
        except:
            addr = 'Empty Address'
        #print(addr)
        #abn = soup.find('div', class_="box__Box-sc-1u3aqjl-0 kxddET").('a').text
        #print(abn)
        try:
            ratting = soup.find(
            "div", {'class': 'Rating__RatingText-sc-1r9ytu8-1 jIdgkl'}).text
        except:
            ratting = 'Empty Ratting'
        #print(ratting)
        try:
            abn = (re.search('abn\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', soup.text).group(1))
        except:
            abn = 'Empty ABN'
        #print(abn)
        try:
            website = (re.search('website\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', soup.text).group(1))
        except:
            website = 'Empty Website'
        #print(website )
        try:
            phone = (re.search('phone\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', soup.text).group(1))
        except:
            phone = 'Empty Phone No'
        #print(phone)
        try:
            cell = (re.search('mobile\\\\":\\\\"(.*?)\\\\"', soup.text).group(1))
        except:
            cell = 'Empty Cell No'
        #print(cell)

        data = {
        'title'         : title,
        'peron name'    : person,
        'address'       : addr,
        'phone no'      : phone,
        'cell no'       : cell,
        'abn no'        : abn,
        'website'       : website
        }
        return data
def get_index_data(soup):
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    titles = []
    for item in soup.findAll("h3", {'class': 'sc-bZQynM sc-iwsKbI dpKmnV'}):
        urls = (f"https://hipages.com.au{item.previous_element.get('href')}")
        titles.append(urls)
    #print(titles)
    return titles

def Main():
    url = "https://hipages.com.au/connect/abcelectricservicespl/service/126298"
    mainurl = "https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/nsw/sydney"
    main_titles = get_index_data(get_page(mainurl))
    for title in main_titles:
        data1 = get_detail_data(get_page(title))
        print(data1)


Main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your data from the script tag rather than the spans and divs.

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize
import json

def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml') 
    return soup

def get_detail_data(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    raw = res.text.split("<script> window.__INITIAL_STATE__=")[1]
    raw = raw.split("</script>")[0]
    data = json.loads(raw)
    data = json.loads(data)

    cols = ['abn', 'address', 'name', 'primary_location', 'service_area', 'state', 'suburb', 'website']

    df = pd.DataFrame(data["sites"]["list"]).T
    df = df[cols].reset_index(drop=True)

    primary_location = json_normalize(df.primary_location[0])
    df = pd.concat([df, primary_location], axis=1)
    to_drop = ["primary_location", "is_primary", "suburb_seo_key", "capital_city_seo_key"]
    df.drop(to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)

    return df


def get_index_data(soup):
    titles = []
    for item in soup.findAll("h3", {'class': 'sc-bZQynM sc-iwsKbI dpKmnV'}):
        urls = (f"https://hipages.com.au{item.previous_element.get('href')}")
        titles.append(urls)
    return titles

def Main():
    mainurl = "https://hipages.com.au/find/antenna_services/nsw/sydney"
    main_titles = get_index_data(get_page(mainurl))  
    final_data = [] 
    for title in main_titles:
        data = get_detail_data(title)
        final_data.append(data)
    return final_data

data = Main()

df = pd.concat(data).reset_index(drop=True)
display(df)
```

This gives you much more detailed data by the way.

Comment: thank you sir but it didn't solve my issue. Sir you may be noticed if you check the output that if there are some records are missing like person name is missing and program shoul show person name is empty but program is displaying next value in place of person. Sir could you please review the output and try to fix it. I think the main issue is that all the value like 'person name', 'location', 'phone no', 'cell no' have same class and tags so there are no ways (in my knowledege) to differentiate them and scrape them separatily. Please guide me!

Comment: Ok. Will look into it. Have you checked the second approach? Because there the scraping doesn't depend on the text but just parses the raw script data.

Comment: thank you bro! It works but it is not getting phone no as my code was doing. Could you please add phone no function too. and please add some comments to describe your lines of code. Please sir fix this last issue. thank you

Comment: thank you so much sir! It works for me. Sir just two things are missing,email  and person name. Only one email is extracting can you help me to extrcat all emails and person name? Please sir!

Comment: Sir check with this mainurl please: https://hipages.com.au/find/air_conditioning/nsw/sydney       It showing list index is out of range

Comment: Regarding email and person names: You'll find these when you look into `data`. This dict contains all embedded data from the page. For person e.g. check `pd.DataFrame(data["pages"]["list"])`.

Comment: Regarding other URLs you either need to adapt the code yourself or post it as a new question. Good luck with your project! 